# Injecting emails into Kafka or any other message queue

Tags: ruby, linux, apache-kafka, james

So my requirement is :

I have alert emails coming into my email address ( outlook ); I want to move those ( forward ) email to a linux machine so that I can use them to push into a DB.

--> Is there a way to get emails from my outlook box to a folder in Linux machine ( I have looked into apache james but i feel its a overhead )

Any help would be much appreciated

## Was following this :

## https://dzone.com/articles/how-to-ingest-email-into-apache-hadoop-in-real-tim

Thanks.

Comment: What's generating the emails? And what are you doing with them once they're in the database?

Comment: Some alert mechanism and I dont have access to that tool; I am getting them just as an email; Once they are in DB / in a folder on a linux machine I planning to create a tool with those data. @RobinMoffatt

Answer (score 0):

If your Outlook account supports IMAP ([which it may!](https://www.pcworld.com/article/2048652/heres-how-to-use-outlook-coms-long-overdue-imap-support.html%20Which%20it%20may)!) then just use a gem like https://github.com/seattlerb/imap_processor to process and send these messages off. (As far as sending to Kafka, last time I looked https://github.com/zendesk/ruby-kafka looked awesome).

The imap processor gem has some standalone apps you can use, to check to see if your servers are compatible.

If you are in a corporate environment and running Outlook < 2013?? then IMAP might not work. I’d try and set up a filter rule server side that formwarded certain messages to a Gmail account. ?? Or try to set this up client side?